# how does this construct method in each class is working?

Tags: php, laravel, class, object, constructor

I am currently working in laravel 5.3. we are following this approach : controller ->service ->repository -> modal . but i do not what are we passing in the construct methods in each class.
in the below codes the flow goes like this: paycontroller -> Merchant service ->MerchantRepository->modal 
the first one is paycontroller:

```
class PayController extends Controller
{

private $merchantService;
private $paymentService;

private $pay_request_field = array(
    'orderID', 'hashKey','currencyCode','amount'
);

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
// public function __construct()
// {
    // $this->middleware('auth');
// }
public function __construct(MerchantService $merchantService, PaymentService $paymentService){
    $this->merchantService = $merchantService;
    $this->paymentService = $paymentService;
}
```

is the constructor receiving a variable of the MerchantService and Payment service? if so where is the value coming from? im confused here

next is the MerchantService:

```
class MerchantService
{
private $merchantRepository;
private $merchantConfigRepository;
private $merchantPaymentRepository;

private $merchant;
private $merchantConfig;
private $merchantPayment;

public function __construct(MerchantRepository $merchantRepository, MerchantConfigRepository $merchantConfigRepository, MerchantPaymentRepository $merchantPaymentRepository){
    $this->merchantRepository = $merchantRepository;
    $this->merchantConfigRepository = $merchantConfigRepository;
    $this->merchantPaymentRepository = $merchantPaymentRepository;
}

public function getMerchantById($id){
    $this->merchant = $this->merchantRepository->getMerchantById($id);
    $this->merchantConfig = $this->merchantConfigRepository->getMerchantConfig($this->merchant->mid);
    return $this->merchant->toArray();
```

then the MerchantRepository:

```
class MerchantRepository
{
private $merchant;

public function __construct(Merchant $merchant){
    $this->merchant = $merchant;
}   

public function getMerchantByHash($hashKey="",$status='action'){
    return $this->merchant->where([["hashKey","=",trim($hashKey)],["status","=",$status]])->firstOrFail();

}
public function getMerchantById($mid="",$status='action'){
    return $this->merchant->where([["mid","=",trim($mid)],["status","=",$status]])->firstOrFail();
}
```

}

Then finally the Modal:

```
class Merchant extends Model
{

protected $connection = 'mysql1';

//Table Name
protected $table = 'merchants';

//Primary Key
protected $primaryKey = 'mid';
```

}

so whats my overall question is, what is going on in this whole process, and the constructors( parameters) where are they coming from.

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have any use statements before class declaration

Comment: what do you mean by use statements ? the paycontroller is triggered from a form submission

Comment: @MohamedManas I suppose you have some lack of knowledge. Have a look in this series and you might get some point on why you are doing `Dependency Injection`:
https://laracasts.com/series/solid-principles-in-php

Comment: If you know its Dependency Injection then why don't you ask for php DI like- http://php-di.org/doc/understanding-di.html

Comment: @paladiN you are right thx for mentioning about DI... i just made myself clear about the concept of dependency injection.. however...i understand that we are passing a (MerchantService $merchantservice) in pay controller which will is like saying we are expecting a MerchantService object right? but forexample see the code below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example you are initializing the `User` and `Database` using the [`new` keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.new)

Like:

```
$database = new Database('host', 'user', 'pass', 'dbname');
$user = new User($database);
```

And using the `new` keyword you need to manually resolve the `dependency` of the class you are initializing.
I have just pasted a line from here:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.new

> An object will always be created unless the object has a constructor
>   defined that throws an exception on error. Classes should be defined
>   before instantiation (and in some cases this is a requirement)

Here for this block of code:

```
public function __construct(MerchantService $merchantService, PaymentService $paymentService){
    $this->merchantService = $merchantService;
    $this->paymentService = $paymentService;
}
```

**You are adding it to the `constructor` of your `Controller` and you are lucky that all the dirty works are done for you by Laravel. i.e. `dependency` of the Controller will be automatically resolved for you by `Laravel`.**

Laravel 5 has great dependency injection and you don't need to worry about from where the dependency is resolved.

Just have a look at this dependency Injection

> http://slashnode.com/dependency-injection/

I hope you understood the differences.

Comment: thx for your explanation... ooh so u mean when i do smthng like this   : public function __construct(MerchantService $merchantService, PaymentService $paymentService){
    $this->merchantService = $merchantService;
    $this->paymentService = $paymentService;
}

Comment: thx for your explanation... ooh so u mean when i do smthng like this : public function __construct(MerchantService $merchantService, PaymentService $paymentService){ $this->merchantService = $merchantService; $this->paymentService = $paymentService; } ....this is equivalent to $merchantservice = new MerchantService ? the difference is that its creating that in the constuctor ?

Answer (score 0):

```
class User 
{
private $database = null;

public function __construct(Database $database) {
    $this->database = $database;
}

public function getUsers() {
    return $this->database->getAll('users');
}
}

$database = new Database('host', 'user', 'pass', 'dbname');
$user = new User($database);
$user->getUsers();
```

so in the above example, we are actually initiating a database object and passing it to the class's constructor. so my question is wwhere is this value of $merchant service being initiated and coming from ?

```
public function __construct(MerchantService $merchantService, PaymentService $paymentService){
$this->merchantService = $merchantService;
$this->paymentService = $paymentService;
}
```

in the above example of class, we can actually see that the $database is actually initiated outside the class...so i just dont understand where is the $merchantservice being initiated...